Strict compilation (-Werror -Wpedantic) only for my project files on esp-idf
I'm trying to build a project with esp-idf, where my files use -Wpedantic, but I'm getting some errors in the framework files.
This is my project structure:
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp

./CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(my-project)

./main/CMakeLists.txt:
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.cpp"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                       PRIV_REQUIRES "lwip")

set(MY_FLAGS
    "-Wall"
    "-Wextra"
    "-Wpedantic"
    "-Werror"
    "-Werror=unused-function"
    "-Werror=unused-variable"
    "-Werror=unused-but-set-variable"
    "-Werror=deprecated-declarations"
)

target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PRIVATE ${MY_FLAGS})

./main/main.cpp:
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "lwip/sockets.h"

const char *TAG = "wifi_manager";

extern "C" void app_main() {
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Hello world");
}

When I compile the project, I get these errors:

In file included from /home/adrian/repos/stack-overflow-example/main/main.cpp:2:
/home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/lwip/sockets.h:8:2: error: #include_next is a GCC extension [-Werror]
    8 | #include_next "lwip/sockets.h"
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32xx/include/arch/cc.h:12,
                 from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include/lwip/arch.h:48,
                 from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include/lwip/debug.h:40,
                 from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include/lwip/opt.h:52,
                 from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include/lwip/sockets.h:42,
                 from /home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/lwip/sockets.h:8:
/home/adrian/repos/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/errno.h:10:2: error: #include_next is a GCC extension [-Werror]
   10 | #include_next "errno.h"
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

My expectation is that the -Wpedantic flag would only apply to my files, so I wouldn't get these errors

Sorry about that. lwip is part of esp-idf. I have updated my question with a full minimal example.

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do in your CMakeLists.txt. The ESP-IDF vendors do not seem to try to link their project when -Wpedantic in a client is used. This cmake function should be fixed by them, or you can modify it locally in your directory:
  macro(__component_add_include_dirs lib dirs type)
      foreach(dir ${dirs})
          get_filename_component(_dir ${dir} ABSOLUTE BASE_DIR 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
          if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${_dir})
              message(FATAL_ERROR "Include directory '${_dir}' is not a directory.")
          endif()
-         target_include_directories(${lib} ${type} ${_dir})
+         target_include_directories(${lib} SYSTEM ${type} ${_dir})
      endforeach()
  endmacro()

